# How can I change the position of the numbers in an OL list?

Tags: html, css, image, list, html-lists

This is the HTML of the OL list that I'm working on. It is supposed to have images but I don't know how to add them here. What I want to do is have the numbers show up on the upper side of the image, instead of the lower side. Their default position seems to be the bottom-left. I want them to show up on the top-left. I tried messing around with the margins, even the padding. Nothing seems to work.

This is pretty much just part of a little project I'm working on to I guess reverse engineer some websites that I go to, and see if I can make copies of them on my own without looking at any of their code.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <head><title></title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">

 </head>
 <body>
 <ol class="mostPopGames">

 <li class="popGames"><img class="listImage" src="images/homepage    /featuredContent/340706.png"/></li>

 <li class="popGames"><img class="listImage" src="images/homepage  /featuredContent/itachi.jpg"/></li>

 <li class="popGames"><img class="listImage" src="images/homepage/featuredContent/kakashi.jpg"/></li>

 <li class="popGames"><img class="listImage" src="images/homepage/featuredContent/tsunade.jpg"/></li>

 <li class="popGames"><img class="listImage" src="images/homepage/featuredContent/340706.png"/></li>

 <li class="popGames"><img class="listImage" src="images/homepage/featuredContent/itachi.jpg"/></li>

 <li class="popGames"><img class="listImage" src="images/homepage/featuredContent/kakashi.jpg"/></li>

 <li class="popGames"><img class="listImage" src="images/homepage/featuredContent/tsunade.jpg"/></li>

 <li class="popGames"><img class="listImage" src="images/homepage/featuredContent/340706.png"/></li>

 <li class="popGames"><img class="listImage" src="images/homepage/featuredContent/itachi.jpg"/></li>
 </ol>
 </body>
 </html>
```

This is the CSS...

```
 ol.mostPopGames{
 margin-left: 0;
 margin-right: 0;
 list-style-type: none;
 }

 ol.mostPopGames li{
 counter-increment: step-counter;}


 ol.mostPopGames li::before{
 content: counter(step-counter);
 margin-right: 5px; 
 font-size: 100%;
 font-weight: bold; 
 padding: 3px 8px;}

 img.listImage{
 width: 20%;
 height: 20%;}
```

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `vertical-align: top;` to the `img` element.

Here is a working example:

```css
ol.mostPopGames{
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ol.mostPopGames li{
  counter-increment: step-counter;
}
ol.mostPopGames li::before{
  content: counter(step-counter);
  margin-right: 5px; 
  font-size: 100%;
  font-weight: bold; 
  padding: 3px 8px;}

img.listImage{
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
}
.mostPopGames li img {
  vertical-align: top;  
}
```

```html
<ol class="mostPopGames">
  <li class="popGames"><img class="listImage" src="https://dummyimage.com/150x100/FF0000/fff"/></li>
  <li class="popGames"><img class="listImage" src="https://dummyimage.com/150x100/00FF00/fff"/></li>
  <li class="popGames"><img class="listImage" src="https://dummyimage.com/150x100/0000FF/fff"/></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: hmm, that actually has the same issue. the number is still showing up in the bottom-left of the image.

Comment: Did some editing that made some problem. check now :)

Answer (score 0):

Tested the snippet by Dekel, seems like the counter still appear on bottom left.

So adding on to that, you can set the position of the counter to absolute and set the to 0. By doing this, you'll need to add margin to the actual image to push it to the right of the counter.

```css
ol.mostPopGames{
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ol.mostPopGames li{
  position: relative;
  counter-increment: step-counter;
}
ol.mostPopGames li::before{
  position: absolute;
  content: counter(step-counter);
  margin-right: 5px; 
  font-size: 100%;
  font-weight: bold; 
  padding: 3px 8px;
  top: 0;
}

img.listImage{
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
  margin-left: 25px;
}
mostPopGames.mostPopGames li {
  vertical-align: top;  
}
```

```html
<ol class="mostPopGames">
  <li class="popGames"><img class="listImage" src="https://dummyimage.com/150x100/FF0000/fff"/></li>
  <li class="popGames"><img class="listImage" src="https://dummyimage.com/150x100/00FF00/fff"/></li>
  <li class="popGames"><img class="listImage" src="https://dummyimage.com/150x100/0000FF/fff"/></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: there was a problem in the css in my example due to several editings. You can check now, everything works there...

Comment: Saw your updated answer. Much better and simpler solution.

Comment: Okay, both of those worked fine. It also works by just putting vertical-align:top; in the ol.mostPopGames li::before{} section...